# FreeRADIUS3とSAMBA4での認証

Tags: samba

こんにちは

■環境情報
FreeRADIUS 3.0.12
Samba 4.7.5
RHEL 7.2

FreeRADIUSとSambaを使用し、VPNの認証サーバーを作ろうとしています。
パスワードの有効期限が切れた際に、VPNクライアントから変更できる必要があります。
そのため、MS-CHAPV2を使用して認証をしたいです。

```
radtest -t mschap testuser testuserpw localhost 0 testing123
```

ユーザー名とパスワードが正しいですが、以下のエラーが出力されます。

```
(0) mschap: ERROR: Program returned code (1) and output 'The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information. (0xc000006d)'
(0) mschap: External script failed
(0) mschap: ERROR: External script says: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information. (0xc000006d)
(0) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
(0)     [mschap] = reject
(0)   } # authenticate = reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Login incorrect (mschap: Program returned code (1) and output 'The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information. (0xc000006d)'): [testuser02/<via Auth-Type = mschap>] (from client localhost port 0)
```

原因わかりますでしょうか。
必要な設定等教えていただきたいです。

Comment: FreeRADIUS と Samba4 は ntml_auth で連携しているのでしょうか？
まずは、ntml_auth コマンド単独で認証できるか試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: いや、待って。
radtest -- radiusd 間を MS-CHAPv2 で認証するのであれば、radiusd が平文パスワードまたは NT-Password/LM-Password を知っている必要があります。
ntml_auth で Samba4 と連携する場合、radiusd -- Samba 間が MS-CHAPv2 になりますが、radtest -- radiusd 間は平文じゃないとダメなのでは？

Comment: ntlm_authでSamba4と連携する場合、radiusdとSamba間でMS-CHAPV2になるということは、FreeRADIUS側では/etc/raddb/mods-enable/mschapの設定は不要ということでしょうか。

Comment: ntlm_authコマンドでの認証はできています。
またradtestでmschapを指定しない場合も認証できることを確認できています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント欄にも書きましたが、RADIUSクライアント -- radiusd 間を MS-CHAPv2 で認証するのであれば、radiusd が平文パスワードまたは NT-Password/LM-Password を知っている必要があります。
mods-config/files/authorize ファイル(旧 users ファイル)とか、LDAP とか。

これとは別に、ntlm_auth で Samba4 と連携する場合、RADIUSクライアント -- Samba 間が MS-CHAPv2 になります(ntlm_auth が中継役)。

----(以下、間違い、ここから)----
これとは別に、ntml_auth で Samba4 と連携する場合、radiusd -- Samba 間が MS-CHAPv2 になります。
ntlm_auth コマンドの引数を見るとわかると思いますが、平文のパスワードが必要です。
つまり、RADIUSクライアントから平文パスワードが渡される必要があります。
"radtest -t mschap" だと平文パスワードが渡されないですし、ntlm_auth モジュールではなく、mschap モジュールで認証を試み、失敗するのだと思います。
----(間違い、ここまで)----

> パスワードの有効期限が切れた際に、VPNクライアントから変更できる必要があります。

Samba のパスワードを変更したいのですよね？
これと、RADIUSクライアントからの MS-CHAPv2 認証が結びつかないのですが、どういうことを想定していらっしゃるのでしょうか？

Comment: やりたい事としては、VPNクライアントでVPN認証時に、パスワード期限が切れていた際にパスワード変更画面が端末側に表示され、パスワード変更ができるようにしたいです。
それを実現するには、MSCHAPV2のエラーコード648を端末側で受信することによって実現できると認識しています。
そのため、VPNクライアントとRADIUSサーバー間でmschapv2を使用する必要があると思い、radtestにmschapを指定しました。
ntlm_authの認証がMSCHAPV2の場合、MSCHAPV2のエラーコードがRADIUSサーバーからVPNクライアントまで連携されるか分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: VPNクライアントが認証する相手は RADIUS でも Samba でもなく、VPNサーバーです。
RADIUS も Samba も、VPN 接続する前は VPNクライアントからは見えないので、その経路ではパスワード変更はできないと思うのですが。

「>> MSCHAPV2のエラーコードがRADIUSサーバーからVPNクライアントまで連携されるか分かりますでしょうか。」

Windows から RADIUSサーバーに RADIUSプロトコルで認証する機会はないと思うのですが、もし、あったとしても、プロトコルが違うので無理だと思います。

Comment: `ntlm_auth --request-nt-key  ...` や `ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=ntlm-server-1 ...` なら平文パスワードは不要です。詳しくは ntlm_auth(1) を参照のこと。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ntlm_auth の箇所、間違っていました。